# Placing scattered objects on surface properly

Tags: scatter-objects-addon

Edit: I've taken out the additional content that's not relevant (add-on related). My apologies for not realising it was off-topic, but it makes sense now, and I completely understand. Thank you for the helpful suggestions! I'll work on adjusting the steps for the origin and particle system as advised by the fantastic users below. Many thanks!

---

I recently got back into Blender after not using it for **years**. I've been trying out the Gscatter add-on, which has been very useful in creating grassy environments. While using low-poly mode, I liked what I saw with the round balls. Can I recreate this effect somehow?

[image: Image I want to replicate, at least conceptually]

[image]

Comment: I don't know Gscatter (and it's off-topic here, being a third-party addon), but it's possible that you'll need to set the origin of your balls to their bottom to get them to sit on the surface. Try going into Edit mode with one of your spheres selected, hit A to select all then G Z and move it up until the bottom is level with the object's origin (yellow dot). Then see if that sphere color is sitting correctly.

Comment: Hi, Der8 .. John Eason  is right, strictly, this post is off-topic here, we can't hope to deal with the full range of 3rd-party add-ons. There's been a vote to close.. but I'm  holding off,  with the suggestion that you revise your question, simply to ask how to achieve the illustrated effect. If your question definitely has to be  about how to use Gscatter, you will have to ask its own developers or community.  I hope you understand, we do want to be helpful.

Comment: @RobinBetts Apologies for not realising that this content was off-topic. I've removed the add-on details and added a note at the beginning of the post. You may consider closing the question as I intend to focus on adjusting the particle system and changing the object's origin (solutions suggested in this thread). If I have any further inquiries, I'll create a new question. Many thanks to this incredibly supportive community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your addon probably uses *Instancing*, you'll have more control on how the particles are orientated if you use a particle system (or geometry nodes):

Put your particle objects in a collection, rotate their mesh -90° on X (and remember that their origin will determine their location on the ground). Select your floor and give it a particle system (*Hair*), activate the *Advanced* option, choose the number of particles, activate the *Rotation* option, choose *Orientation Axis > Normal*, randomize a bit if you don't want your particles to be completely aligned with the normals, tweak the *Randomize Phase* so that the particles rotate on their Z. Under *Render* choose *Render As > Collection* and under *Instance Collection* select your collection, tweak *Scale* and *Scale Randomness*:

[image]

Edit: You need to disable the *Whole Collection* option, it uses the whole collection as one object so each object’s origin won’t be taken into account, also, if you want the spheres to be precisely placed on their base, put the origin at this position on each sphere (see image, it’s the side view) and set the *Randomize* of the *Orientation Axis* to 0:

[image]

Comment: So, I positioned the origin for the spheres at the base of each sphere and followed your provided screenshot (ty!) However, despite this adjustment, the spheres still appear to be half way on the plane unless I select 'whole collection' under Render -> Instance -> Instance Collection. Upon doing so, the spheres are properly aligned (no longer halfway within the plane), but now many of them are clustered at the bottom of the plane.

(Sorry, i have very few characters left and no way of adding a screenshot it seems!)

Comment: Could you please share your file? remove all the useless objects, save and use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform like workupload

Comment: I've edited, the main problem is that you've enabled the Whole Collection option

Comment: Thank you!!! Your instructions fixed the issue!

Some spheres appear to be merging together. Is there an option I can adjust to prevent this from happening? Also, do you have any suggestions on how to cover the entire field with spheres? I'm currently experimenting with the Emission -> Number settings. 

Apologies if these questions are off-topic or not allowed. Nonetheless, I appreciate that my main issue has been resolved. Thank you once again!

Comment: just wanted to make an edit to add that I was able to unmerge the spheres by playing around with 'number' and 'seeds', I'm not entirely sure why it works but it did the trick for now. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Seed just change the pattern, it won't really prevent the intersecting between particles, but some seeds may work better than others. You cant really avoid particle intersecting, except with some tricks (maybe with Emit particles, I can't find the tutorial)